# SQL: Concatenate two DATEPART functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return a column by concatenating two `DATEPART` functions.

```
SELECT DATEPART ( ww , [Date] ) + '-' + DATEPART ( yy , [Date] ) as Date, [Email], count(url) as Pages_Visited
From [Log]
WHERE UserId IS NOT NULL and UserId != 0
GROUP BY DATEPART ( ww , [Date] ) + '-' + DATEPART ( yy , [Date] ), [Email]
```

The result I derive is the addition of the results two functions. What I require is the string concatenation. 
For example if the two `DATEPARTS` return `12` and `15` respectively I need the result to look like `12-15` but for now I get `27`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to nvarchar first:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(3), DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())) 
        + N'-' + CONVERT(nvarchar(3), DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()))
```

Or if you are using `varchar` then simply remove `N` leading string.

Answer (score 2):

Cast them to varchars explicitly.

What is happening is that '-' is being implicitly converted to -0, and then added with the other two numbers!